# If using the Stripe PHP SDK, do I need to be PCI compliant, still?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, pci-compliance

I simply would like to be able to use Stripe's PHP SDK to verify credit card information, and I don't intend to store the CC info in my system, at all. The only stuff I would want to save is a boolean for valid / invalid.

If the CC number only *passes through* my server, do I still need to be fully PCI compliant? Or would SSL be enough?

Answer (score 0):

You are required to be PCI compliant if you process credit card information, no matter how you process it. What changes is what is needed to PCI complaint. That depends on how many transactions you process as well as how you process the transactions. Thus processing fewer transactions and never touching the card details means its easier to be PCI compliant than if you do 1 million transactions and store the card details.

With Stripe, you normally have to be compliant per PCI SAQ A, however that assumes you're going the normal route of using Stripe.js or Stripe Checkout to obtain a card token. That is about 12 pages of paperwork which Stripe even pre-fills out for you. If you decide that your server should get the card data, even if it does nothing with the data or just passes it through to Stripe without storing it, you fall into PCI SAQ D which is about 80 pages of paperwork which makes sure that the server is fully PCI complaint (its audited, password changes, is in a secure datacenter, etc).